# External HP monitor has black border with Dell Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a new Dell laptop running Windows 7 and connected an extra HP S2031 monitor I had through a digital cable.

It has an Intel 3000 chipset.

I now have a black border around my screen on the HP external monitor. I have tried scaling (it says it's at 100%), I have tried finding some sort of overscan/underscan option, but none are available.

The HP site says the monitor does this with other chipsets, but does not mention Intel. When it does mention Intel it says there is an option to increase the scaling by selecting *Scale*, then *Full Screen* — well, that is not an option under my "scaling" menu.